# Como fazer um insert com colunas e valores vindos de um select?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Imagine a seguinte situação:** Executar uma consulta em um banco de dados para adquirir uma determinada linha de registro, e então inseri-la novamente na mesma tabela ao fim dos registros.

É possível que eu consiga inserir os dados novamente na tabela sem que eu precise mencionar no comando de `INSERT` o que *compõe* essa a linha de registro? 
Digo, eu preciso mesmo mencionar que para:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table WHERE t = "12:00:00"

       +----------+------+------+--------- -+
       | t        | val  | lead | lead diff |
       +----------+------+------+-----------+
       | 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
       +----------+------+------+-----------+
```

O código correspondente será:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table (t, val, lead, lead diff) VALUES ("12:00:00", 100, 125, -25);
```

Ou existe uma maneira de tornar o `INSERT` mais *generalista*? (Sem mencionar tudo).

Comment: Dei uma contextualizada no título da pergunta. Caso considere indevido, pode reverter a edição na [revisão da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/367066/revisions). ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível! Basta **não informar** a cláusula `values` substituindo-a por uma *query* `select`.

Veja na prática (sem aplicar a cláusula `where`):

```
> INSERT INTO `insert_select` VALUES ('12:00:00', 100, 125, -25);
> SELECT * FROM `insert_select`;
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| t        | val  | lead | lead_diff |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
+----------+------+------+-----------+

----> Aqui é onde sua dúvida é resolvida:
> INSERT INTO `insert_select` (`val`, `lead`) SELECT `val`, `lead` FROM `insert_select`;

> SELECT * FROM `insert_select`;
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| t        | val  | lead | lead_diff |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
| NULL     |  100 |  125 |         0 |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
```

Repare que especifiquei as colunas. Mas pode, também, utilizar o coringa `*`:

```
> INSERT INTO `insert_select` SELECT * FROM `insert_select`;
> SELECT * FROM `insert_select`;
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| t        | val  | lead | lead_diff |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
| 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
| 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
+----------+------+------+-----------+
```

> Fonte: [Database Administrators - insert with multiple row return through select](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215787/insert-with-multiple-row-return-through-select) (em inglês)
>
> E tem mais na documentação do MySQL: [13.2.6.1 INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) (em inglês)

Answer (score -3):

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table WHERE t = "12:00:00";
```